# Problems checking Apache2 installation in Ubuntu

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04

successfully installed Apache2 in remote machine(ubuntu) for a new user using s`udo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install apache2`  checked whether the apache is running in remote machine for new user

```
studentthree@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/$ service apache2 status
* apache2 is running
```

checked if port 80 is opened in firewall set up.

```
studentthree@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To Action From

22 ALLOW Anywhere
2222/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
80/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
22 (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
2222/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
```

When i test [localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080) in my local machine i am getting webpage not available?
Could someone please assist in overcoming this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking port 80 and accessing  port 8080. Make sure port 8080 is open and you said you installed apache on remote server so you should use IP of remote server instead of localhost. Also check on which port you are running apache.

Comment: `studentthree@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
1872/apache2
studentthree@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :8000
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN
1872/apache2` i have givent access to both ports installed vagrant and accessing the remote machine. so local host should work to my guess